# How to determine sewer line access for a sink install?

Tags: plumbing

My garage needs a sink. Water is not going to be a problem. Drainage however, no clue. The closest drain is in the adjacent laundry room but unfortunately on the opposite[image] wall (see diagram).

I'm pretty sure we don't have our own septic and it just runs into the sewer. I've inspected some of the blue prints for the home but there is no information about drainage to be found. I don't know where to go from here.Is tapping into the washer drain doable?

I cant run a hose to the outside. I do a lot in the garage and don't want the waste water dumped on the neighbors grass, I'm already killing the vegetation doing that.

---

Jim Some excellent questions and considerations, thank you:

This may somewhat limit the amounts and types of detergent and the temperature of the discharged water. (trying to avoid major limitations. I don't plan on putting plutonium down there but I would like to keep capable of handling stong detergents and solvents. )

You might have to install a cooling tank. What do you plan to use this sink for? (a lot of different stuff some solvents, paint, cleaning mop, waste from servicing a vehicle. All this in small amounts but large enough to kill the vegetation it would be dumping on. I know this cause I've already killed all the vegetation outside dumping waste water there (hence I'm trying to fix that problem)!!,

Do you have a sink in the laundry room? (no but there is drain for the washing machine)

What is on the other side of the garage wall opposite the water heater? (wifes bedroom, no drian until you get to the other side of her bedroom (where the center of the house is and most the plumbing is located)

Where does the temperature/pressure relief pipe on the water heater terminate (it terminates onto the floor right next to the heater, pathetic I know, correcting that is on my to do list.

Comment: You should consider draining the sink into the side yard or backyard. This would enable waste "grey water" from  the sink to be used to irrigate some vegetation. A lot of people do this even if it violates the local code. This may somewhat limit the amounts and types of detergent and the temperature of the discharged water.  You might have to install a cooling tank.  What do you plan to use this sink for? Do you have a sink in the laundry room? What is on the other side of the garage wall opposite the water heater? Where does the temperature/pressure relief pipe on the water heater terminate?

Comment: @JimStewart Jim i've added my answers to querstions

Comment: If you're in the house and you can't find the drain lines, then I don't know how someone who's never even  seen the house can find them.

Comment: Solvents and even latex paint (except trace levels) should not go into the drain. The only thing that should go into the drain is human waste (black water) and grey water waste (lavatories, tub/shower, sink, dshwasher, utility sink, clothes washer). We take all paint to the city toxic waste disposal facility. I had a sink put into my garage across a wall from a bathroom. The sink drain was connected to a vertical sewer vent. I use this sink for drawing water for mopping and for disposal of floor mopping waste (dirty warm water with detergent). I also wash dog bowls and dirty bird feeders, etc.

Comment: @Mike Baranczak I would accept this as an answer i think \